# jQuery: delete dynamically created table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, jquery-selectors

I want to delete table row that is created dynamically. New table row is created when `Add New` is clicked. I could delete only the table rows that already loaded.

Please help me point out the problem with code.

---

**.html**

```
<table id="fresh-table" class="table table-striped option-list table-hover table-sm">
 <thead class="thead-table-list">
  <tr>
   <th scope="col">Option</th>
   <th scope="col">Answer</th>
   <th></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tboy>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="Animal"></td>
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="F"></td>
   <td><i class="material-icons option-delete">delete</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="Snake"></td>
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="T"></td>
   <td><i class="material-icons option-delete">delete</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="Eagle"></td>
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="F"></td>
   <td><i class="material-icons option-delete">delete</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="Turtle"></td>
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="F"></td>
   <td><i class="material-icons option-delete">delete</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="3"><u id="add_option">Add New</u></td>
  </tr>
 </tboy>
</table>
```

---

**.js**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//Add option row-- QCM
$("#add_option").click(function(){
  $('.option-list tr:nth-last-child(2)').after('<tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="Turtle"></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="F"></td><td><i class="material-icons option-delete">delete</i></td></tr>');
});

//Delete option_row onClick
$('td i').on('click',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});
</script>
```

Anything wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `td` is dynamically create your jquery cannot find the dynamically created `td` object so to find the dynamically created `td` you need to take reference of static element or object. For example `<table id="fresh-table" class="table table-striped option-list table-hover table-sm"></table>` is not a dynamic element. So you can use

```
$('#fresh-table').on('click','td i',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});
```

```js
//Add option row-- QCM
$("#add_option").click(function(){
  $('.option-list tr:nth-last-child(2)').after('<tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="Turtle"></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="F"></td><td><i class="material-icons option-delete">delete</i></td></tr>');
});

//Delete option_row onClick
$('#fresh-table').on('click','td i',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="fresh-table" class="table table-striped option-list table-hover table-sm">
 <thead class="thead-table-list">
  <tr>
   <th scope="col">Option</th>
   <th scope="col">Answer</th>
   <th></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="Animal"></td>
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="F"></td>
   <td><i class="material-icons option-delete">delete</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="Snake"></td>
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="T"></td>
   <td><i class="material-icons option-delete">delete</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="Eagle"></td>
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="F"></td>
   <td><i class="material-icons option-delete">delete</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="Turtle"></td>
   <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="F"></td>
   <td><i class="material-icons option-delete">delete</i></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="3"><u id="add_option">Add New</u></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have a typo, it should be `<tbody>` and not `<tboy>`

To add event listeners to dynamically added elements. You can add the event to `<body>` like `$("body").on('click', 'td i', function(e) {` You might want to  use class instead of `td i` as selector.

```js
$("#add_option").click(function() {
  $('.option-list tr:nth-last-child(2)').after('<tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="Turtle"></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="F"></td><td><i class="material-icons option-delete">delete</i></td></tr>');
});

$("body").on('click', 'td i', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="fresh-table" class="table table-striped option-list table-hover table-sm">
  <thead class="thead-table-list">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Option</th>
      <th scope="col">Answer</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="Animal"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="F"></td>
      <td><i class="material-icons option-delete">delete</i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="Snake"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="T"></td>
      <td><i class="material-icons option-delete">delete</i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="Eagle"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="F"></td>
      <td><i class="material-icons option-delete">delete</i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="Turtle"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="F"></td>
      <td><i class="material-icons option-delete">delete</i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><u id="add_option">Add New</u></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```